# Account subclass object creation

Tags: java, instance, subclass

So I have a question on how to create instances of a sub class in JAVA. Yes, this is a homework assignment for a grade, I have fully implemented a main class with a default and a paramaterized constructor for an Account class.

I have created two sub classes, Savings and Checking. The only specifications from the book for the assignment were that the Checking account cannot withdraw past an overdraft limit, and that the Savings account cannot overdraw at all.

```
class Checking extends Account{
        double overdraftLimit = -100;

        public void withdraw(double w) {
            if (balance - w < overdraftLimit)
                    System.out.println("You can't overdraft more than $100.");
            else
                balance = balance - w;
        }    
    }

class Savings extends Account{
        double overdraftLimit = 0;

        public void withdraw (double w) {
            if (balance - w < overdraftLimit)
                    System.out.println("You don't have enough money, fool.");
            else
                balance = balance - w;
        }
    }
```

My problem is that I'm not sure how to create an instance of a specific subclass, either `Savings` or `Checking`. Does anyone have suggestions for me? In my parent class, `Account`, I already have a method for `withdraw ( double w )`, such that the`balance -= w`. I overrode the withdraw method in each of my subclasses already. My code compiles and runs, but in the problem I am instructed to write a test program that creates an object of type `Account`, `Savings`, `Checking` and invokes their `toString()` method. I've talked to my instructor and this problem wasn't fully completed before printing because there are no instructions on the overdraft limit allowed for the `Checking` account.

There is also no mention of the `toString()` method that I am supposed to be invoking so I am skipping that part of the assignment.

Comment: just a suggestion: in both of your `withdraw` methods you have `else balance = balance - w;`, I would consider changing that to `else super(w)`.

Comment: @Jeeter probably means `super.withdraw(w)`.

Comment: Whoops!  Thanks for catching that @Keppil!

Comment: @user3571411 Did my answer work for you? If so, mark it as resolved

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly (and feel free to clarify), you need to create a constructor for each of the classes:

```
public Checking(){
    super();
    //other initialization
}

public Savings(){
    super();
    //other initialization
}
```

and call them from your `main` with the keyword `new`:

```
Savings mySavings = new Savings();
Checking myChecking = new Checking();
Account myAccount = new Account();
```

Comment: No need for the `super()` calls, they are done automatically.

Comment: I will try to implement your suggestion tomorrow @Jeeter, I've tried to create an instance of Savings using the classname objectname = new classname. (i.e. Savings mySavings = newSavings();) which should have activated the default constructor from my Account class, but for some reason it didn't. But I am tired so not sure if it's doing what I want it to. Thanks for your help and I'll update this thread tomorrow

Comment: Just for clarification for myself, because I'm still just slightly confused about invoking the super() method. If I take your suggestion about invoking super(w) in my else statements, then I would include balance -= w in the method definition? Just so I'm clear, whenever I invoke the super() method in a subclass then it will automatically connect itself to a method in the parent class with the same parameters? That's what's been confusing me because I can imagine methods in the main class with the same inputs that would do different things. (i.e. getPerimeter, getArea, ...)

Comment: Here's the thing: When you call the `withdraw` method in `Savings` of `Checking`, what you're doing is basically: 1) Is it too much to withdraw? 2) if it isn't, **behave like a normal account**. This behavior should already be defined in your `Account`'s `withdraw` method. Essentially, if there's nothing special happening in the account, it's just `super.withdraw(w)`, because you're passing that responsibility to code that's already there, not redefining it for every single class.